# MPU-9250 : How to convert pitch (+90/-90) to 360 degree?

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, c++

I'm using Arduino Uno with MPU-9250 to find roll, pitch and yaw.

Everything works fine but I want to covert pitch from (+90/-90) to 360 degree.

I'm using this code:

```
vec.setX(atan2(2.0 * (m_data[2] * m_data[3] + m_data[0] * m_data[1]),
        1 - 2.0 * (m_data[1] * m_data[1] + m_data[2] * m_data[2])));

vec.setY(asin(2.0 * (m_data[0] * m_data[2] - m_data[1] * m_data[3])));

vec.setZ(atan2(2.0 * (m_data[1] * m_data[2] + m_data[0] * m_data[3]),
        1 - 2.0 * (m_data[2] * m_data[2] + m_data[3] * m_data[3])));     

m_data[0] = scalar;

m_data[1] = x;

m_data[2] = y;

m_data[3] = z;
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to map the range `-90...-1` to `270...359` and the range `0...90` to `0...90`?

It's simple enough:

```
if (angle < 0) 
    angle = 360 + angle;
```

Note that you are *adding the negative value* to 360, which is the same as *subtracting the positive value*.

*Or* do you want to map it so that -90 is 0 and +90 is 360?  In that case you need to offset and scale it:

```
angle = angle + 90; // Angle is now 0..180
angle = angle * 2; // angle is now 0...360
```

Or in one line:

```
angle = (angle + 90) * 2;
```

Comment: this answer is completely wrong. In the first case you are creating something that will range from `0 to 90` and then from `270 to 360`. In the second case, adding 90 and multiplying by two will create a 0 to 360 range mapped to a 180 degree movement, meaning that every degree the accelerometer rotates in that axis will result in a 2 degrees output.

Comment: @SpaceDog You are saying that it is wrong, then proceeding to say that it is wrong because it does what it is designed to do. I don't understand how that can be wrong. In case 1 yes it is intended to range from 0-90 and 270 to 360. In case 2, yes, it is intended to range from 0-360 in 2-degree steps. Given the vagueness of the question the two interpretations of what is wanted are perfectly reasonable, and the two cases given (which you have confirmed in your "it is wrong") are correct solutions to them. If it is wrong at least say why it is wrong, not why it is right.

Comment: it is wrong because the poster probably needs the pitch to be from 0 to 360 degrees in 1 degree step. What I mean is this: suppose the rotating object rotates just along the pitch axis, I mean, the object does a 360 degrees pitch axis turn. Supposing the object is at 0 degrees when it started it will go 0 → 90 → 0 → -90 → 0. Look at this in a graph it will appear that the object rotated from 0 to 90 and back to 0 but in fact the object continued to rotate in the same direction. This is probably the reason why it would be nice to get a scale where you can represent the real movement.

Comment: @SpaceDog You are reading things into the question that aren't there, and ignoring things that are there. The pitch only goes from -90 to +90. How can it be doing a 360 turn if it only goes from -90 to +90? If it goes past 90 in either direction it's upside down and will plummet to earth. At that point the resolution of your data is the least of your worries.

Comment: what about a loop? Isn't a loop a 360 pitch revolution?

Comment: @SpaceDog Again you are making dangerous assumptions. Not all devices will be able to make a loop. At least not without incredibly clever flying. It takes an amazingly good pilot to do a loop in a helicopter for instance. The only person able to judge if this answer has made the correct assumptions is the person asking the question. The person asking the question has said the answer is correct, so the assumptions made in the answer must therefore be correct.  You are basically saying that you know better than the OP what the OP is asking, which is mighty presumptuous of you.

Comment: @SpaceDog Besides: THE OP STATES -90 TO +90!  If it was doing a loop they wouldn't state that. They would state -180 to +180!

Answer (score 1):

The equations in you example convert a quaternion representation of rotation into euler angles correctly; The "pitch" euler angle only has a valid range of +90/-90 and changing it will make your angular representation invalid.

Euler angles specify an arbitrary rotation by 3 consecutive turns. You may want "apparent angle with the horizon", which is not the same thing, and does not define a sequential set of turns to get from rotation A to B.

To get pitch and roll with the horizon from a quaternion, I think you want something like:

```
float x = 2*m_data[1]*m_data[3] - 2*m_data[2]*m_data[0];
float y = 2*m_data[1]*m_data[0] + 2*m_data[2]*m_data[3];
float z = 1 - 2*m_data[2]*m_data[2] - 2*m_data[1]*m_data[1];

float pitch = atan2(y,z);
float roll  = atan2(x,z);
```

I got this by rotating the vector <0,0,1> by the quaternion and then measuring the angles of the result around x and y axis. This kind of freaks out when one of the angles is close to 90 degrees though; there are probably better equations out there.

"Yaw vs the horizon" doesn't make any sense, and people usually want the same "style" of yaw you are getting from the euler angle equations, so that shouldn't change.